# How can i get post with multiple dynamic taxonomies

Tags: wordpress

I am filtering custom post types using ajax. I am able to filter using single taxonomy but how to filter results with multiple taxonomies.

This is the query i tried:

### Code:

```
$args=array('orderby'=>'date','post_status'=>'publish');

//sort by bank if isset
if(isset($_POST['bank']))
{
    $args['tax_query']=array(
        array(
                'taxonomy'=>'banks',
                'field'=>'id',
                'terms'=>$_POST['bank']
        )
    );
}
if(isset($_POST['card_type']))
{
    $args['tax_query']=array(
        'relation'=>'AND',
        array(
                'taxonomy'=>'cardtype',
                'field'=>'id',
                'terms'=>$_POST['card_type']
        )
    );
}
$query=new WP_Query($args);
```

But it only shows result with filtering from one taxonomy not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are working on right track but a small mistake in argument may cause result to be rendered wrong.
Instead of `'relation'=>'AND'`, use `'relation'=>'OR'`

`'relation'=>'AND'` will fetch result when both taxonomy condition match, while `'relation'=>'OR'` condition will compare with any of the taxonomy.

[click here to view the WP Query arguments](https://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/)

Actually yout array formation is wrong for `tax_query`.
Please check updated code below.
If you don't use `$args['tax_query']['relation']=   'AND'`, then also it will work for you.

Please have a try with below code snippet.Update you code with below snippet.

```
$args = array(
            'orderby'=>'date',
            'post_status'=>'publish'
        );

//sort by bank if isset
if(isset($_POST['bank'])){
    $args['tax_query'][]= array(
                'taxonomy'=>'banks',
                'field'=>'id',
                'terms'=>$_POST['bank']
                );
}
if(isset($_POST['card_type'])){
    $args['tax_query']['relation']=   'AND';//you can remove this

    $args['tax_query'][]=   array(
                            'taxonomy'=>'cardtype',
                            'field'=>'id',
                            'terms'=>$_POST['card_type']
                    );

}
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: i want the result where both argument matches else show not found.. if one argument is set then show result according to one argument if not found then show no result found..

Comment: Please check updated snippet for your issue. Hope this will help you @denny